DLOGTIME sequential access (uniformity conditions for circuits)
Consider the direct connection language of a circuit family, consisting of tuples (a,p,b,y) where

a is a gate number
p a binary string is an encoding for a predecessor or type
b is a gate type or predecessor of a according to p
Y is any string of length n

A Dlogtime turing machine M has no input read head, instead, it has an index tape which is initialized normally. M has a special query state that allows it to immediately see the character on the input whose address is written on the index tape in binary. If this address is out of bounds, M has access to this information too (this seems to be standard in vollmers text, as well as other papers)
I am reading BIS 90, uniformity in NC1. Consider a polynomial size circuit family bounded by some $n^k$, whose direct connection language is decidable in dlog time. It seems that our machine M needs access to the first 3k log n positions or so in order to decide whether any given tuple is in the language ( ie it needs to be able to read a,p,b)
I can mimic sequential access by repeatedly adding one to the index tape, then querying. Following BIS 90, addition of a log n number is easily done in log n. However, accessing the first log n positions then involves log n operations each of complexity log n reulting in complexity O(log n x log n) , which asymptotically is too much.
So perhaps a counter will do. it is easy to design a subroutine that determines log n and then runs for k log n times. But iterating the index while updating for carries still requires O(log n) passes.
How do I obtain sequential access for the first O(log n) positions? Am i misunderstanding anything here?
